# Binding a host address to localhost in Linux

Tags: linux, hostname, loopback

How to bind the example.com address to the local box?

I'm enhancing a website, which is written so that 'example.com' is hard coded as its host. How do I do a loop back in Firefox in response to a 'example.com' request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add '127.0.0.1 example.com' to the /etc/hosts file:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 127.0.0.1    example.com >> /etc/hosts'
```

This will be system wide, not just for firefox.

Comment: life saving trick. for windows users, you can edit windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to get same result.